# The average rate of job submissions in a busy computer center is 4 per minute.

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

If it can be assumed that the number of submissions per minute interval is Poisson distributed, calculate the probability that

(a) at least two jobs will be submitted in any minute

$P(X\geq 2)$ so $1-(P(x=0) + P(x=1) + P(x=2)) = 0.7618967$

(b) no job will be submitted in any minute

$P(x=0)$ so $((e^{-4})\cdot (4^0))/0! = 0.018315$

(c) not more than one job will be submitted in any one-minute interval.

$P(X\leq 1)$ so $(P(x=0) + P(x=1))$

Please let me know if my answer/way of approaching the problem is right. Thank you.

Comment: For at least two jobs we want $1-(\Pr(X=0)+\Pr(X=1))$.

Comment: oh, ok thank you!! but part b and c is right?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, sorry, I should have said the other two are right. (I have not checked the arithmetic.) Note that one finds the answer to c) on the way to answering a).